# Could not cast value of type '__NSCFData' to 'NSDate'

Tags: ios, swift, nsdate, nsuserdefaults

I have an NSUserdefault that I either set as nil, or a Date, I am trying to retrieve it and believe the below code should work, however i get the following error in the console when printing and trying to run the code stating its in some NSCFData format? I havent set it to be this anywhere so wondered where its pulling this data type from thats breaking the app?

```
let timerStoppingDate = UserDefaults.standard.object(forKey: "setStopDate") as! Date
```

> THE SETSTOPDATE USERDEFAULT IS SET AS Optional(<62706c69 73743030 d4010203 04050608 09582476 65727369 6f6e5824 6f626a65 63747359 24617263 68697665 72542474 6f701200 0186a0a1 0755246e 756c6c5f 100f4e53 4b657965 64417263 68697665 72d10a0b 54726f6f 74800008 111a232d 3237393f 51545900 00000000 00010100 00000000 00000c00 00000000 00000000 00000000 00005b>)
>    Could not cast value of type '__NSCFData' (0x109b0f680) to 'NSDate' (0x109b10080).

and its set here:

```
    func createTimer(stopDate: Date) {
    print("CONSTRUCTING A TIMER")
    userDefaults.set(stopDate, forKey: "setStopDate")
```

I believe at the point its failing it should be set as nil, so it nil a NSCFData type?

Comment: I can't reproduce this. Do you have a small, complete example (say in a command-line app) that demonstrates? http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve

Comment: Im not sure i have the technical ability to do so, really its pretty simple which is why i cant see the issue, i set the userdefault when they run a timer, if they dont run it, it should read nil, i have no idea why its populated by this datatype at all

Comment: I expect that at some point something else gets set to `setStopDate`. It is not uncommon for people to mistype "Date" as "Data". I would place breakpoints at each time you change the user defaults, read it back in the debugger and see what you actually wrote.

Comment: that was my thought, i ran a search through the instances of setStopDate and its not the case, its always either Date (via a variable) or nil, ill check for the 5th time

Comment: I can confirm its only ever set in 1 VC in the app and that VC contains no uses of the word 'data'

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Its not an ideal answer, but i changed the key name so i had a fresh UserDefault and it resolved the issue, perhaps the old key was corrupted, nothing else was altered and the new key name makes everything work fine

Comment: Or you could have delete the app from the simulator/device and ran it again. That would have clear the user defaults.